# Index formula excel

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

my formula below is giving me results from correct columns but from WRONG rows. 
On sheet Dashborad I am inputing part number into P4 which will be searched in sheet Tooling in column A and then first value from sheet TOOLING, from column H will be returned:

```
=INDEX(TOOLING!$H:$H,SMALL(IF(DASHBOARD!$P$4=TOOLING!$A:$A,ROW(TOOLING!$A:$A)-ROW(INDEX(A$1,1,1))+1),1))
```

(Then I will use it for second and third found values)

Thanks for whatever advice.

Answer (score 1):

If tooling!a:a contains text then,

```
=INDEX(tooling!H:H, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(tooling!A$1:INDEX(tooling!A:A, MATCH("zzz", tooling!A:A)))/(tooling!A$1:INDEX(tooling!A:A, MATCH("zzz", tooling!A:A))=DASHBOARD!$P$4), ROW(1:1)))
```

If tooling!a:a contains numbers then,

```
=INDEX(tooling!H:H, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(tooling!A$1:INDEX(tooling!A:A, MATCH(1e99, tooling!A:A)))/(tooling!A$1:INDEX(tooling!A:A, MATCH(1e99, tooling!A:A))=DASHBOARD!$P$4), ROW(1:1)))
```

Comment: Hello Jeeped,
tooling contains text. I copied the formula but it does not work for me.
Is it possible to adjsut the formula which I posted above so that it works?
I will now need some time to understand that long formula you posted.

Comment: Have you checked if the version of excel you are using supports the aggregate() function?

Comment: Yes, Excel 2010 supports. However, I probably should have clarified better what I need. In DASHBOARD! I have cells D8,D9,D10. In D8 I could use normal VLOOKUP which would return me the first founded value from top from TOOLING!. In D9 I would need the second founded value from top and in cell D10 I would need the third founded value from top in sheet TOOLING!

Comment: My formula above is working! I only forgot to put ctrl+shift+enter